# dc brushless motor shuts off automatically

Tags: motor, controller

I'm trying to see whether my electric bike's dc brushless motor controller (input 24 V) is repairable. The problem is that when I adjust the throttle to the highest power and release, the motor controller clicks and power stops going to the motor. I have to turn the power off and on to get it working again. (I am able to maintain medium speeds without the controller automatically turning off.

Would this be due to a safety mechanism preventing too much current from damaging the motor? I measured input voltage to the controller by putting my multimeter in series with the hot wires and got a reading of 50V (motor controller input is 24V). Please let me know if I diagnosed the problem correctly and what can be done to resolve it. I've attached pictures of the wiring diagram, motor controller specs and multimeter reading below.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: "I measured input voltage to the controller by putting my multimeter in series with the hot wires" - voltage is measured in _parallel_ across a circuit, not inserted in series with it. Your meter is set to 250V **AC**. To measure DC voltage you need to select a **DC** Volt range (white numbers).  What are these 'hot' wires you speak of?

Comment: duly noted - the hot wires im speaking of are the red ones wrapped around the wire leds (black/red). Why would it be reading voltage if the settings were incorrect?

Comment: On AC Volts the meter is calibrated for the lower average voltage of a half-wave rectified sine wave. It will still respond to DC but the reading will be high. "...the red ones wrapped around the wire leds (black/red)." - so the red wires are the positive lead coming from the battery, which you have cut and inserted the meter into, right? If so you should reconnect it and connect the meter between the read and black wires to measure the battery voltage. Then watch the voltage while slowly increasing power until the controller cuts out. What reading do you get just before it cuts?

Comment: the meter read 25 volts when i put it in parallel, and did not change by the time the it cut

Comment: actually it read closer to 30 v, but the reading didnt change as i added power